# Identifying groups of individuals if conditional occurence in one of them

Tags: r, conditional-statements, plyr

I'm trying to identify (using a binary 1/0 variable) groups of subjects from a database, whenever at least one subject from this group fulfills two conditions.

My database `DF`is composed of families with description of sex and age of each member (and family ID `family`)  : I would like to create a new, binary variable `NoMan` which would be 0 if at least one of the males from a family  (`sx` with attribute `1`) is **aged more** than 16y., otherwise it would take the value 1. Note that I want `NoMan`to be identical for all members from the same family.

```
family <- factor(rep(c("001","002","003"), c(10,8,15)),
                 levels=c("001","002","003"), labels=c("001","002","003"), ordered=TRUE)
ag <- c(22,8,4,2,55,9,44,65,1,7,32,2,2,1,6,9,18,99,73,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,18,11,22,33)
sx <- c(1,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,1,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,2,2,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,2)
DF <- data.frame(family, ag, sx)
DF
```

I have tried to use `ddply`combined with `ifelse` but this was not successful :

```
DF <- ddply(DF,.(family), transform, NoMan=ifelse(sx==1 & ag>16, 1, 0))
DF
```

It seems that among eventual other limitation, in this script the functions apply to individuals instead of families (I actually would like them to apply the same result to all members of the same family).

I feel I'm on the right tracks, but maybe someone has a good solution to this problem?

PS: just edited `DF` because in this example I wanted all members from family 003 to be tagged as `NoMan==1`

Comment: Thank you Uwe Block

Comment: As you have changed the Q, all the answers - in particular the accepted one by _S van Balen_ - should be modified as well, I guess.

Comment: Indeed Uwe Block, my mistake... the condition for age should all be  `ag>16`. Most answers worked very well here. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    DF$NoMan = c(! DF$family %in% unique(DF[DF$sx == 1 & DF$ag < 16,1]))
```

Comment: I like em on one line ;) Plus this saves you a library for what it's worth.

Answer (score 1):

`ifelse` returns a vector of results disregard the group, you can use `any` to aggregate the results per group:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(DF, .(family), transform, NoMan = +any(sx == 1 & ag < 16))
```

Comment: Thank you, but using this one i just had  `1` as values for `NoMan` : should we specify the outcome of the conditions as in `ifelse`? ex. when to take value 0, and when to take value 1 ? Thank you!

Comment: That depends on how you want your data to be. This logic is based on *binary variable NoMan which would be 0 if at least one of the males from a family (sx with attribute 1) is less than 16y*. And surely, for your sample data, all families contains at least one male whose age is less than 16. And your description is different from your code. Maybe you want `ddply(DF, .(family), transform, NoMan = +!any(sx == 1 & ag < 16))`

Comment: Sorry ! you were right and i have changed this in the data, this should work now with the new `DF`? ..  But i still get 1's only  as the output (or 0's from your last script).

Comment: The data still contains three families and every family has at least one record that is male and age < 16. Shouldn't NoMan be all the same across the data frame? Or maybe you could show some desired output in your question.

Comment: Sorry again, your solution works fine but i presented my problem without being careful enough : i wanted the value "1" whenever one male was aged more than 16 !  `DF <- ddply(DF, .(family), transform, NoMan = +!any(sx == 1 & ag > 16)) ; DF`

Comment: Just thinking about it for a few days... using this last script, what if i wanted to add another condition to the first one, like i would like NoMan to be taking the value `1`also if `family =="003" ` ? This time this second condition isn't negative (not `+!any(...) ` but instead something like: `+any(family=="003")` ... i tried to combine it with our first expression (above) but this does not seem to work.. Thank you if you can help me understand this, again...

Answer (score 1):

We can use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
DF %>%
   group_by(family) %>% 
   mutate(NoMan = as.integer(any(sx == 1 & ag < 16)))
```

---

Or using `ave` from `base R`

```
DF$NoMan <- with(DF, as.integer(ave(sx==1 & ag < 16, family, FUN = any)))
```

Comment: Thank you, but this fist solution did not work when i tried. Your second solution works fine but binary variable values are reversed (0 instead of 1 and vice versa).

Comment: @den I used `dplyr_0.5.0` and it is working for me.  With regards to second solution, if you need the reverse, just do `with(DF, as.integer(!ave(sx==1 & ag < 16, family, FUN = any)))` or change the conditions

Comment: Great ! `DF$NoMan <- with(DF, as.integer(!ave(sx==1 & ag > 16, family, FUN = any))) `  works fine

Answer (score 1):

```
#Obtain unique families
family = c(unique(as.character(DF$family)))
NoMan  = c()

for (i in 1:length(family)){
#Subset a new dataframe for each family with only male members and check if minimun age is below 16
if (min(subset(DF,DF$family == family[1] & DF$sx=="1")$ag) < 16){
NoMan[i] = 1
} else {
NoMan[i] = 0
}
}

#Join unique family and NoMan into new dataframe
DF2 = cbind(family,NoMan)

#Use lookup command of qdapTools package
library(qdapTools)
DF$NoMan = lookup(DF$family,DF2)
```